# Karate - driver config start failed , getting ReadTimeout error, while trying to launch mobile application using Appium 2.0

Tags: karate, appium-android

---

Getting read timeout error in karate while automation mobile app using Appium 2.0 and uiautomator2.

I've recently upgraded my appium server from 1.x to 2.x in my system and updated the desired capabilities to w3c standards in karate-config.js and updated the driver config as per latest updates in https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-core/README.md#driver. since the driver is installed as a separate component now in Appium 2.0.

---

Below is my driver config

```
* def session = { capabilities: "#(android.desiredConfig)" }
* configure driver = { type: 'android',   webDriverUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:4723/", start:       false, httpConfig : { readTimeout: 120000 }}
* driver { webDriverSession: '#(session)' }
```

appium is running(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Jl4.png)

time out error1 in karate report (https://i.stack.imgur.com/52iQd.png)
issue in ide (https://i.stack.imgur.com/foSv0.png)

Comment: karate's mobile support is a little experimental. if you can contribute code or info - please do so - else you may want to consider other options